# Realistic Ocean Wave

Tags: rendering, modifiers

1. Please how can I get the Flip Fluids without watermark?
2. I have an academic project to create a model which simulates ocean wave in a coastal setting. So far, what I have done does not appear so realistic, so I would appreciate any suggestion(s) on how to improve this result.
   Thank you[image]

Comment: 1.) By paying for it! 2.) That's a third-party addon anyway, not part of Blender so questions about it are off-topic here. The description and instructions about the demo version seem to be [here](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/FLIP-Fluids-Demo-Addon).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Please read this post carefully: [Concerning third-party addons and question closing](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/concerning-third-party-addons-and-question-closing). Since this is a paid addon, I would ask you to contact the author of the addon with your question and ask him for advice. Thank you for your understanding!

Comment: I would be interested to know if you know the reason why there is a watermark? :D